# Apache2 - .app virtual hosting error

Tags: virtualbox, apache2, hosting

I am trying to host a **xyz.app** URL on Apache. I've configured everything on my server, but I am not even receiving anything on access.log. On the same server, I am already hosting .com website which is working fine. Following is the environment I'm using;

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Server: Apache/2.4.41

My **xyz.conf** file is as following;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName xyz.app

        <Directory "/var/www/xyzapp">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        # ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/xyzapp

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

my **apachectl -S** output is as follows;

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server xyz.app (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xyz.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost xyz.app (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/xyz.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost aaa.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/aaa.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

I have tried traceroute from other machines and tracing is successful to the server, so my DNS configuration is all right. Also, I've check directly using HTTP://IP and it is taking me to landing page. But my xyz.app URL is not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you *enabled* the config and restarted Apache? `sudo a2ensite {filename}.conf` and `sudo service apache2 restart` may be all you need.

Comment: Yes. Already done that

Comment: Hopefully there is no special settings for .app URLs

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a couple of days, I've figured out the issue. Posting here so it might help anyone in future.
I've verified my network calls and it showed me that whenever I was trying calling HTTP, it would redirect me to HTTPS (even if I edited the URL and tried again). To check it I stumble upon [this post](https://pk.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/APP-Forwarding-Issues/td-p/113832) at the GoDaddy forum with the following information

> This is because they are expected to have HTTPS by the browser since
> they come with free SSL (per the domain registry).

So I upgraded my HTTP hosting with an SSL certificate and everything was running smooth. Apparently, there wasn't any configuration issue and it had to do with the URL and .app domain.